# Update 2 table columns based on latest date from another table

Tags: mysql

I have searched this site and tried quite a few sql variations but cannot seem to get the correct result.

I have two tables, one named "events", the other named "outstanding".  I have added a two columns to the outstanding table "Last_event" and "Event_date".  The unique identifier for each table is "Account_number".  I am trying to lookup all events in the "events" table for an Account_number where the "Event_name" field contains "Collections" and then find the most recent correlating "Created_date".  That date will be saved in the "outstanding" table "Event_date" field and the correlating "Event_name" will be saved in the "Last_event" field.

Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE outstanding as C 
inner join (SELECT l.Account_number, e.Created_date, e.Event_name 
            FROM outstanding l 
            INNER JOIN events e on(l.Account_number = e.Account_number) 
            WHERE Event_name LIKE 'Collections:%'
            ORDER BY `e`.`Created_date` desc) AS D on(C.Account_number = D.Account_number) 
set C.Event_date = D.`Created_date`, 
    C.Last_event = D.`Event_name`
```

This is very close to working, however, if there is more than one event, it saved the first "Event_name" alphabetically.

If more info is needed, let me know.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is sample data:

events table:

[image]

outstanding table:

[image]

expected results:

[image]

Here are the table structures:

events table:
[image: events table]

outstanding table:
[image: outstanding table]

Comment: Hi there, can you [provide minimal sample data plus expected results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)? If the other fields/columns are unrelated to the question, please omit them. Thanks

Comment: I have added some example data in the question, please let me know if you need more info.  I added them as images because I don't know how to add a table to the question.  FYI @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `INNER JOIN` is more complex than you need. All you really want is the most recent (maximum) date associated with an event on the account which has the word `'Collections'` in its name. Note that since your dates are not in MySQL format, you need to convert them before you can test them. You can that do with this query:

```
UPDATE outstanding as C 
inner join (SELECT Account_number, Created_date, Event_name 
            FROM events e
            WHERE Event_name LIKE '%Collections%' AND
               STR_TO_DATE(Created_date, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Created_date, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i')) 
                               FROM events e1
                               WHERE e1.Account_Number = e.Account_Number AND
                                     e1.Event_name LIKE '%Collections%')
            ) AS D on (C.Account_number = D.Account_number) 
set C.Event_date = D.Created_date, 
    C.Last_event = D.`Event_name`
```

Contents of table after `UPDATE` (based on your sample data):

```
id  Account_number  Last_event                                  Event_date
19  8599            Collections: Sent to Outside Collections    2/16/18 0:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03245a5a5f02b58f309da2885baeaff4)

**Update**

Based on the fiddle supplied, the dates in the table are actually in `dd/mm/YYYY HH:mm` format, not `dd/mm/yy HH:mm` as was shown in the sample data in the question. So the calls to `STR_TO_DATE` need to be adjusted:

```
UPDATE outstanding as C 
inner join (SELECT Account_number, Created_date, Event_name 
            FROM events e
            WHERE Event_name LIKE '%Collections%' AND
               STR_TO_DATE(Created_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Created_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) 
                               FROM events e1
                               WHERE e1.Account_Number = e.Account_Number AND
                                     e1.Event_name LIKE '%Collections%')
            ) AS D on (C.Account_number = D.Account_number) 
set C.Event_date = D.Created_date, 
    C.Last_event = D.`Event_name`
```

[Updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4c1715f92267a513d6bb0f2e3271b46)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I am getting the following error message:
#1054 - Unknown column 'e.Account_number' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry @Rob a small typo. I've corrected it in my edit.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, when I run that query, it says 0 rows affected, however, almost every record should get updated.

Comment: @Rob sorry. Without sample data it's hard to get these right.

Comment: @Rob thanks for supplying the sample data (although it would have made life much easier if it was text!). Anyway I've updated the query - the issue was that your dates are not in a MySQL recognised format - and created a demo showing it working.

Comment: Thanks for providing the updated query.  I see it is working in the dbfiddle but for some reason I am still getting 0 rows affected when running it.

Comment: It looks like it's an incorrect datetime value, take a look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce3d5606c45d1d7d0fa35e46440a6ec3)

Comment: @Rob see my edit and updated [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4c1715f92267a513d6bb0f2e3271b46). The problem was the date format in your table wasn't the same as in the sample data you posted.

Comment: Thank you, that works!  I appreciate your patience and assistance.